# Renaming duplicate files in a folder

Tags: python, file-rename

I am renaming lot of my call files. The files are saved as:

020171707p+917348809123.m4a

02016p+917348809123.m4a

020171707p+918658644125.m4a

020171707p+913676876817.m4a

I am using regex to display only digits after the + sign.
But i get an error since 2 files cannot have the same name. how can i modify the code so that both new files(only slightly different in name) remain in the same folder.

Here is my code:

```
import re
import os
path="D:\\docu\s\mjay\docu\\acr"
DIR=os.chdir(path)
newstr=".m4a"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
   match=re.search("p\+(\d+)",filename)
   if match==None:
     continue
   newfilename=match.group(1)+newstr
   os.rename(filename,newfilename)
```

Comment: Append a valid integer suffix to any duplicate found.

Answer (score 0):

here is an easy fix

```
import os
count = 1
path = "D:\\docu\s\mjay\docu\\acr\\"

for filename in os.listdir(path):   
    try:
        f_name = filename.split("+")[1]
        f_name = f_name.split(".")[0]+"."+f_name.split(".")[1]
        os.rename(path+filename,path+f_name)
        count +=1
    except:
        f_name = filename.split("+")[1]
        f_name = f_name.split(".")[0]+str(count)+"."+f_name.split(".")[1]
        os.rename(path+filename,path+f_name)
        count+=1
```